# Cannot boot ubuntu 20 APCI BIOS error AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT

Tags: acpi

I am installing ubuntu 20 desktop on my machine. It is having intel server board S5000VSASASR and 2 GB of RAM

I am getting following error
acpi error ae_aml_buffer_limit field cpb3 at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target buffer 64 bits[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JOb0.jpg)